# Bootstrap nav pushes content below around when hovering over links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigationbar

I found some similar problems but I didn't find solution to mine, because mine has some simple animations on it. So lets get down to it. I recorded short 10 second clip which showcases my problem, please look at it [HERE](https://youtu.be/Tm7Xquewmtw). Please also take a look at this [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Pt20wtPZoD). Thank you for help, I just can't wrap my mind around this. 
HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="">Women</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Men</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Junior</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Accesories</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Collections</a></li>
                    <li><a href=""><span style="color:#f05050;">Sale</span></a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="">My Account</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.navbar {
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.navbar-default {
    border-width: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #000000;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .open > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > ul > li, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li.focus > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:visited, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li:hover > a:hover {
    background-image: #1c2b36;
    background: #1c2b36;
    background-color: #1c2b36 !important;
    color: #FFF;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #3bc0c3;
    -webkit-transition: all ease-in .1s;
    -o-transition: all ease-in .1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease-in .1s;
    -ms-transition: all ease-in .1s;
    transition: all ease-in .1s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The border applied takes up the extra space hence it pushes it down.
Try this for the li element or a element, Whichever draws a border when you hover on it. mostly the `li` tag i guess

```
.navbar-nav>li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

(OR)

you can add an invisible `border-bottom` to `li` elements so that when it is hovered, only the color changes and the contents are not pushed down.Like this:

```
.navbar-nav>li {
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent;
}
```

EDIT:

According to your bootply do this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-brand, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #000000;
    border-bottom:5px solid transparent; //add this in CSS already present there
}
```

Comment: Didn't solve it, but thanks for fast reply. Here is a bootply if that helps http://www.bootply.com/Pt20wtPZoD

Comment: So simple >_<. Thank you very much Sir!

Comment: If it helped you, mark it as answer so that this question remains solved :)